# How can I preview with audio in After Effects and be able to pause / resume the preview?

Tags: after-effects

I am working on a series of animations which have elements that are timed to the beat of the background track in AE. It's crucial that they are lined up perfectly to the audio (they are DJ training videos).

I'm used to Premiere, but am pretty new to After Effects. In Premiere you can preview the audio by pressing space, and then press space again to stop the preview. In After Effects, when you do this there is no audio.

The only way I've been able to get a preview with audio is to use the RAM preview, but when I press space to stop it, it goes back to the beginning of the timeline / render area.

I need to be able to listen to the audio, and then stop it on a beat so the timeline marker is in the right place for an effect / keyframe. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

To enable the audio playback, only way is to use the **RAM-Preview**. Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> or the associated <kbd>|||></kbd> in the **Preview Panel** to start the preview rendering process:

[image]

- Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> **again** to stop it
- Press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> **twice** to stop and playback the previously rendered (green) frames

In terms of correct audio playback:

- Set the *Frame Rate* to the composition settings
- Enable *From Current Time* option
- Enable *Sound Preview* (6th button in the first row)

In order to facilitate the work:

1. Set the **rendering resolution** of the view to a lower value for e.g. to **half** or **quarter**
2. Limit the **work area** in your timeline, press <kbd>B</kbd> to set the start render point (Begin), press <kbd>N</kbd> to set the end point (End)
3. Enable **Loop** preview (7th button) to repeat the preview of the current work area

**Note:** As @Emir Dupovac mentioned, also check your waveform:

[image]

See this related answer: [AE - Composition video file/layer missing audio](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/ae-composition-video-file-layer-missing-audio/15332#15332)

Comment: Is there any way to pause the RAM preview? I want to be able to listen for a beat, and pause so the timeline marker is on the beat. Best workaround I've seen so far is to add a keyframe on the fly with *, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @Ben To loop something you can set your work area, with B and N for Begin and End. You can also use flags and drag it into the timeline to mark a specific time.

Answer (score 2):

You can hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and **drag timeline marker** which will play audio, its not perfect, but maybe it will help. And also you can select audio and double tap key <kbd>L</kbd> which will open **waveform** so you can see the beats.